# Types in MaybeT computation

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, option-type

Working in an IO computation I ended up with a staircase of `case mbValue of …`s and figured out that I should use the `Maybe` monad to simplify the code. Since it's within an `IO` computation and I need to get `IO` values, I used the `MaybeT` monad transformer so that I can `lift` `IO` computation into `Maybe`.

Now, I have always thought about values being “stripped” of their `Maybe`ness after an `values <- mbValue` inside a `Maybe` computation, but this turns out to be too simple of a heuristic here.

As highlighted below, when using a `Maybe a` value as an `a` (here by passing it to `read`), it fails to type check:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (runMaybeT)

lol :: IO (Maybe Int)
lol = return (Just 3)

lal :: IO (Maybe String)
lal = return (Just "8")

foo :: IO (Maybe Bool)
foo = do
  b <- runMaybeT $ do
    x <- lift lol
    y <- lift lal
    return (x < (read y)) 
  return b       ^-- Couldn't match type ‘Maybe String’ with ‘String’

main = foo >>= print
```

If I put a typed hole in for `return (x < (read y))`, I see that it expects a `Bool`, which makes sense, but also that the current bindings include

```
||   y :: Data.Maybe.Maybe GHC.Base.String
||     (bound at /private/tmp/test.hs:14:5)
||   x :: Data.Maybe.Maybe GHC.Types.Int
||     (bound at /private/tmp/test.hs:13:5)
```

I.e., `y` is a `Maybe String`. This of course explains the error, but I'm left confused. Where is my understanding wrong, and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: Replace `lift` by the `MaybeT` constructor.

Note that

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

and

```
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

Your use of `lift` in

```
x <- lift lol
```

is at the type

```
lift :: IO (Maybe Int) -> MaybeT IO (Maybe Int)
```

That's why `x` will be a `Maybe Int` again. The `lift` adds a fresh `MaybeT` layer that is independent of the `Maybe` occurrence you already have.

But

```
MaybeT :: m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a
```

instead as in

```
x <- MaybeT lol
```

will be used at type

```
MaybeT :: IO (Maybe a) -> MaybeT IO a
```

and do the right thing.

Answer (score 4):

When specialized to `MaybeT`, `lift :: Monad m => m a -> MaybeT m a`. Since `lol :: IO (Maybe Int)`, `m` is `IO` and `a` is `Maybe Int`, therefore `lift lol :: MaybeT IO (Maybe Int)`.

`IO (Maybe a)` is just the value contained within a `MaybeT IO a` newtype wrapper, so there's no need to lift it; instead use the `MaybeT` constructor, for example as in `MaybeT lol`.

But this is not how people tend to use monad transformers. Instead, just use `MaybeT` values and lift as needed:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (runMaybeT, MaybeT)

lol :: MaybeT IO Int
lol = return 3

lal :: MaybeT IO String
lal = return "8"

foo :: IO (Maybe Bool)
foo = 
  runMaybeT $ do
    x <- lol
    y <- lal

    _ <- lift getLine -- lift (IO String) to MaybeT IO String
    _ <- return 100   -- lift any pure value    
    _ <- mzero        -- use the MonadPlus instance to get a lifted Nothing.

    return (x < (read y)) 

main = foo >>= print
```